# Wpf Prism Modularity config

Tags: wpf, prism, modularity

Can i place my libraries in some where over the internet and load them from cloud each time the app runs instead of being placed beside the *.exe file ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Prism does not provide the functionality to do this in desktop applications as out of the box. However, Prism allows you to extend its functionality by implementing your own versions for some of its components. For this particular case I believe you might need to create your own implementation of an **IModuleTypeLoader** that obtains the files from the cloud instead of the local file system. You can check the **FileModuleTypeLoader** implementation of Prism and use it as a starting point.